# Is there a limit of connected devices in TDLS (802.11z)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, 802.11

I know handshake and link establishment is done at routing level, and then the link works on switching level allowing devices to talk without causing any latency or work burden on the AP, but is there a limit to the number of devices that can use TDLS at the same time in an AP?

Presume the connections are done following a star topology, 1:N.

Comment: I've been hearing about TDLS since like 2013, but I've never heard of any product that actually implements it. There have been a lot of provisions of various standards, including 802.11 standards, that no one has ever implemented, or that never caught on in the marketplace. Are you aware of any products that implement TDLS?

Comment: Google Nearby connections does. The docs state that devices connect by Bluetooth/BLE and then upgrade to Wi-Fi hotspots (if possible). However, an engineer working on nearby mentioned that both devices may use TDLS if some criteria is met (reachable SSID, same AP...) https://stackoverflow.com/a/65588012/7060082